# What is the best way to read/parse the XML files

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, xml

I have bunch of these XML files that I would like to read and store the data in a SQL table. What is the best way to read/parse the XML files? I am working with ASP.NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008. I am very good with C#/VB and asp.net but have not had much experience with XML. Basically these are multiple choice questions and there answers. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<assessmentItem xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p0 imsqti_v2p0.xsd" identifier="choice" adaptive="false" timeDependent="false" title="001157" xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsqti_v2p0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <responseDeclaration identifier="RESPONSE" cardinality="single" baseType="identifier">
        <correctResponse>
            <value>A</value>
        </correctResponse>
    </responseDeclaration>
    <outcomeDeclaration identifier="SCORE" cardinality="single" baseType="integer">
        <defaultValue>
            <value>0</value>
        </defaultValue>
    </outcomeDeclaration>
    <stylesheet href="stylesheet/scip.css" type="text/css" />
    <itemBody>
        <span class="class1">
            <b>Nick had eight marbles. He found four more.<br />
                <br />
            </b>
        </span>
        <div class="class2">
            <span class="class1">
                <b>
                    <img src="images/41047.jpg" alt="" />
                </b>
            </span>
        </div>
        <span class="class1">
            <b>How many marbles does Nick have now?</b>
        </span>
        <choiceInteraction responseIdentifier="RESPONSE" shuffle="false" maxChoices="1">
            <simpleChoice identifier="A">
                <span class="class1">12</span>
                <rubricBlock>
                    <span class="class1" >
                        <b>Correct</b>
                    </span>
                </rubricBlock>
            </simpleChoice>
            <simpleChoice identifier="B">
                <span class="class1">8</span>
                <rubricBlock>
                    <span class="class1" >Chose a number from the stem</span>
                </rubricBlock>
            </simpleChoice>
            <simpleChoice identifier="C">
                <span class="class1">4</span>
                <rubricBlock>
                    <span class="class1" >Subtracted</span>
                </rubricBlock>
            </simpleChoice>
        </choiceInteraction>
    </itemBody>
    <responseProcessing template="http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qti_v2p0/rptemplates/match_correct" />
</assessmentItem>
```

Comment: You've effectively doomed yourself by saying this is "multiple choice". A question is expected to have a definitive answer as this is not a forum. It also really helps if you're able to demonstrate that you've attempted to do something yourself which you don't appear to have done.

Answer (score 2):

Your title is misleading. You are asking `What is the best way to read/parse the XML files?` and it has little to do with `Storing XML in a database`.

And I suggest just don't be lazy and read documentation how to do it. Parsing an XML is very common task and no matter what language you're using. You'll find plenty of examples on the web.

Comment: +1 have a look at his/her other question on books (5 mins ago), I told user to google too

Answer (score 1):

**Basically these are multiple choice questions and their answers. What is the best way to read/parse the XML files?**

Let's just get you sorted out now. See here, you will need to read up on some articles and given your good at C# and VB.Net this shouldn't be a problem:

**[Google - Linq To XML examples](http://www.google.com.au/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=LINQ+to+XML+read+xml+into+class)**

One way with this technology is to use a XDoc to load in the XML, then to parse the XML into a Class Object Model use LinqToXML with anonymous types to create the Choice and Answer List Of Classes.

**[Official Microsoft examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/LINQ-to-XML-Language-53971190)**